# Error: File to import not found or unreadable Gulp + Sass

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

im trying to compile *Sass* and refresh the browser with *BrowserSync*. Looks correctly making changes on **styles.scss** file, the problem is with the imported files. When i make some changes i get an error:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: dev\scss\styles.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: base.
       Parent style sheet: C:/xampp/htdocs/test-gulp/dev/scss/styles.scss
        on line 1 of dev/scss/styles.scss
>> @import 'base';
   ^

    at options.error (C:\xampp\htdocs\test-gulp\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
```

This happens sometimes at the first time that i update the **_base.scss** file, but sometimes after the thrid or fourth update.

I made a repository on Github with my setup, hope you can help me: https://github.com/kenramirez12/gulp-sass-browsersync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with your editor and more precisely - with atomic save behaviour. I don't know what text editor you use, but I had the same errors when I coding in sublime, and the solution was adding to the sublime settings this: `"atomic_save": true`. It helped me.

Comment: I use VS Code, i've tried with Sublime adding this line to settings and seems it works fine (before adding this line had the same problem), atm im looking for anything similar for VS Code

Comment: Try to use gulp-wait as described [here](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress/issues/731#issuecomment-275773642)

Comment: Lol, yep gulp-wait was finally the "solution", ty so much!